# NHibernate mapping-by-code and IUsertype not working

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, nhibernate-mapping-by-code, iusertype

I am trying to get a custom type working with NHibernate (v3.3) mapping by code. I tried following this example [here](http://lostechies.com/rayhouston/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype/), but with no luck. The custom type I'm trying to achieve is a one that trims the strings coming from a database.

I am getting the following exception:

> PropertyAccessException: Invalid Cast (check your
>   mapping for property type mismatches). 
>   {"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'ConsoleApplication1.TrimmedString'."}

Here is my full attempt ([gist](https://gist.github.com/pwee167/fbfe509272b77a1b1cff)).

```
public class TrimmedString : IUserType
{
    public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        //treat for the posibility of null values
        string resultString = (string) NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]);
        if (resultString != null)
            return resultString.Trim();
        return null;
    }

    public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, null, index);
            return;
        }

        value = ((string) value).Trim();

        NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, value, index);
    }

    public object DeepCopy(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        return string.Copy((String) value);
    }

    public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
    {
        return original;
    }

    public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
    {
        return DeepCopy(cached);
    }
    public object Disassemble(object value)
    {
        return DeepCopy(value);
    }

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get
        {
            SqlType[] types = new SqlType[1];
            types[0] = new SqlType(DbType.String);
            return types;
        }
    }

    public Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof (String); }
    }

    public bool IsMutable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        var xString = x as string;
        var yString = y as string;
        if (xString == null || yString == null) return false;

        return xString.Equals(yString);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object x)
    {
        return x.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Here is my mapping:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual TrimmedString FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonMap : ClassMapping<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Table("Source");
        Id(i => i.Id);
        Property(i => i.FirstName, map => map.Type<TrimmedString>());
        Property(i => i.LastName);
    }
}
```

Not sure if I have to do anything special in the NHibernate configuration object, but I have included that in the Gist linked above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Person`, it should be...

```
public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
```

..., not `TrimmedString`.  `TrimmedString` is just the class that instructs NHibernate how you want that property to be hydrated and dehydrated.  The property it is applied to should be of the type specified by `ReturnedType` - in other words, `String`.  NHibernate is trying to set the `FirstName` property with a `string` value (because that's what the `TrimmedString` said it should do), but it can't because `FirstName` only allows `TrimmedString`s, hence the "Invalid Cast" error.